# Optimization problems when migrating a function from MS SQL to Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I moved the function to Postgres. In MS SQL, it was executed in less than a second. In Postgresql, it runs for almost 6 minutes. I've been working on this problem for 6 hours, and I haven't found a reason. As I understand it, the problem is in the syntax.

In the xt_ed_registr_grp_led function, I attach the function (xt_ef_registr_pts_all) to a table in this format:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.xt_ef_registr_pts_all(_D_Date, -1, NULL) AS RP_Child
                                    ON RP_Child.link = RG.f_registr_pts
```

Next, I attach the code from MS SQL and Postgres.

Postgres function

```
...
AS
$$
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY SELECT
                     RP.link,
                     RP.f_division,
                     RP.f_subdivision,
                     RP.f_subscr,
                     RP.f_sale_items,
                     RP.f_sale_category,
                     RP.d_date_begin,
                     RP.d_date_end,
                     RCap.f_work_modes AS F_Work_Modes,
                     RP.f_energy_levels,
                     NP.f_conn_points,
                     NP.c_address_short,
                     CASE
                         WHEN COALESCE(Provinces.c_name, '') = ''
                             THEN NULL
                         ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM((COALESCE(LT_Provinces.c_prefix || ' ', '') || COALESCE(Provinces.c_name, ''))))
                     END AS C_Provinces,
                     CASE
                         WHEN COALESCE(Towns.c_name, '') = ''
                             THEN NULL
                         ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM((COALESCE(LT_Towns.c_prefix || ' ', '') || COALESCE(Towns.c_name, ''))))
                     END AS C_Towns,
                     CASE
                         WHEN COALESCE(Municipalities.c_name, '') = ''
                             THEN NULL
                         ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM((COALESCE(LT_Municipalities.c_prefix || ' ', '') || COALESCE(Municipalities.c_name, ''))))
                     END AS C_Municipalities,
                     CASE
                         WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(((COALESCE(LT_Streets.c_prefix || ' ', '') || COALESCE(Streets.c_name, '')) || COALESCE(', ' || CP.c_building_num, '') ||
                                           COALESCE(COALESCE(' ' || sbct.c_short_name, ' ' || sbct.c_name, '/') || CP.c_building_corp, '')))) = ''
                             THEN NULL
                         ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(((COALESCE(LT_Streets.c_prefix || ' ', '') || COALESCE(Streets.c_name, '')) || COALESCE(', ' || CP.c_building_num, '') ||
                                           COALESCE(COALESCE(' ' || sbct.c_short_name, ' ' || sbct.c_name, '/') || CP.c_building_corp, ''))))
                     END AS C_Street_Building,
                     RCM.f_calc_methods,
                     RCM.d_date AS D_Calc_Methods_Date,
                     CASE
                         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT
                                         0
                                     FROM dbo.ed_registr_grp RG1
                                     WHERE RG1.f_registr_pts_main = RP.link
                             )
                             THEN TRUE
                         ELSE FALSE
                     END AS B_Group,
                     CASE
                         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT
                                         0
                                     FROM dbo.ed_registr_grp RG1
                                     WHERE RG1.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                             )
                             THEN TRUE
                         ELSE FALSE
                     END AS B_IncludeGroup,
                     dbo.xt_ef_registr_pts_energy_categ(RP.f_sale_items, RP.f_tariff, RP.f_energy_levels) AS F_Energy_Category,
                     RP.f_registr_pts_prev,
                     D.link AS F_Device,
                     EDP.f_division AS f_device_division,
                     D.n_rate,
                     D.n_rate * dbo.ui_ef_device_transf_rate(D.f_division, D.link, COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())) AS N_Ktf,
                     Dig.c_digits,
                     EDC.c_name AS C_Device_Category_Name,                                                                                    
                     EDC.f_class,
                     D.f_device_types,
                     D.c_serial_number,
                     EDP.f_energy_types,
                     EDP.n_percent2,
                     EDP.b_main AS B_Device_Main,
                     D.d_setup_date,
                     D.d_replace_date,
                     EDP.n_percent,
                     RPT.f_tariff,
                     RPT.d_date::timestamptz(0)::text AS D_Tariff_Date,
                     RPT.f_norms,
                     RCon.n_cons AS N_Cons_Cons,
                     RCon.n_cons2 AS N_Cons_Cons2,
                     RCon.d_date AS D_Cons_Date,
                     RCap.n_cap AS N_Cap_Cons,
                     RCap.n_cap2 AS N_Cap_Cons2,
                     RCap.n_cap3 AS N_Cap_Cons3,
                     RCap.d_date AS D_Cap_Date,
                     RPA.n_rate AS N_Activity_Rate,
                     RPA.d_date AS D_Activity_Date,
                     RP.c_code AS n_code,
                     RP.c_name,
                     RP.f_balance_types,
                     RP.f_balance_type_details,
                     RP.f_balance_types_sec,
                     RP.f_balance_type_details_sec,
                     RP.n_order,
                     RP.b_non_heat_formula,
                     RP.b_line_formula,
                     RP.b_transf_formula,
                     RP.f_transf_types,
                     SDA.link AS F_Areas,
                     erpa.d_date AS D_Areas_Date,
                     RP.b_notinclude,
                     RP.f_form_46,
                     RP.f_cons_category,
                     RP.s_owner,
                     RP.s_create_date,
                     RP.s_modif_date,
                     RP.s_creator,
                     NP.link AS F_Network_Pts,
                     NP.c_code AS C_Network_Pts_Code,
                     NR.c_network_path AS _Bound_F_Network_Pts,
                     NR.c_network_path_short AS C_Network_Path_Short,
                     CASE
                         WHEN NIP.f_parent IS NOT NULL
                             THEN dbo.cf_get_network_name(COALESCE(NI_P.f_networks, NI.f_networks))
                     END AS _Bound_F_Network,
                     FSI.c_name AS _Bound_F_Sale_Items,
                     EDT.c_name || COALESCE(' / ' || EDT.c_modification, '') AS _Bound_F_Device_Types,
                     (dbo.cf_get_c_codename(FT.n_code, FT.c_name) || ' / ' || CAST(COALESCE(FTH.n_tariff, '0') AS text) || 'р.') AS _Bound_F_Tariff,
                     FTH.n_tariff AS N_Tariff1,
                     FTH.n_tariff_2 AS N_Tariff2,
                     EEL.c_name AS _Bound_F_Energy_Levels,
                     ECM.c_name || COALESCE(' / ' || ECM2.c_name, '') AS _Bound_F_Calc_Methods,
                     COALESCE(EBT.c_short_name, EBT.c_name) AS _Bound_F_Balance_Types,
                     COALESCE(EET.c_short_name, EET.c_name) AS _Bound_F_Energy_Types,
                     ESWM.c_name AS _Bound_F_Work_Modes,
                     ELA.c_name AS _Bound_F_Transf_Algorithms,
                     ELA2.c_name AS _Bound_F_Line_Algorithms,
                     ELA3.c_name AS _Bound_F_Non_Heat_Algorithms,
                     SDA.c_name AS _Bound_F_Areas,
                     CP.c_code_cp AS N_Conn_Points_Code,                                                                                     
                     COALESCE(CP.c_name, NP.c_address_short) AS C_Conn_Points_Name,                                                           
                     COALESCE(CPS.c_name, '') || COALESCE(' ' || CT.c_name_short, '') || COALESCE(' № ' || CPS.c_premise_number, '') AS C_Conn_Points_Sub_Name,
                     CPS.c_premise_number AS C_Premise_Number,
                     COALESCE((CPS.j_custom ->> 'j_b_dryers')::bool, (CP.j_custom ->> 'j_b_dryers')::bool) AS B_Polotenchik,                  
                     COALESCE((CPS.j_custom ->> 'j_b_riser_insulation')::bool, (CP.j_custom ->> 'j_b_riser_insulation')::bool) AS B_Isolation, 
                     COALESCE((CPS.j_custom ->> 'j_b_external_gvs')::bool, (CP.j_custom ->> 'j_b_external_gvs')::bool) AS B_OuterGVS,          
                     CP.f_conn_types AS F_Conn_Types,
                     CP.f_conn_status_types AS F_Conn_Status_Types,
                     FSC.c_name AS _Bound_F_Sale_Category,                                                                                     
                     ETT.c_name AS _Bound_F_Transf_Types,
                     FN.c_name AS _Bound_F_Norms,
                     dbo.cf_get_network_name(COALESCE(NI_P.f_networks, NI.f_networks)) AS C_Network_Path,                                   

                     RP.n_graph_form,
                     RP.n_line_loss,
                     RP.n_rp_loss,

                     NP.f_conn_points_sub,

                     RPL_Non_Heat.d_date_begin AS D_Non_Heat_Date,
                     RPL_Non_Heat.n_value AS N_Non_Heat_Waste,
                     RPL_Non_Heat.f_loss_algorithms AS F_Non_Heat_Algorithms,
                     RPL_Line.d_date_begin AS D_Line_Date,
                     RPL_Line.n_value AS N_Line_Waste,
                     RPL_Line.f_loss_algorithms AS F_Line_Algorithms,
                     RPL_Transf.d_date_begin AS D_Transf_Date,
                     RPL_Transf.n_value AS N_Transf_Waste,
                     RPL_Transf.f_loss_algorithms AS F_Transf_Algorithms,

                     s.n_code AS N_Code_Subscr,
                     p.c_name1 AS C_Name_Subscr

                 FROM dbo.ed_registr_pts AS RP

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.sd_subscr AS s
                                ON s.link = RP.f_subscr
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.cd_partners AS p
                                ON p.link = s.f_partners

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_network_pts AS NP
                                ON NP.link = RP.f_network_pts
                               AND NP.b_pod = TRUE
                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (   SELECT
                              NIPX.link,
                              NIPX.f_parent
                          FROM dbo.ed_network_struct NIPX
                          WHERE NIPX.f_child = NP.link
                            AND NIPX.b_pod = TRUE
                            AND NIPX.b_ismain = TRUE
                            AND NIPX.d_date_begin <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                          ORDER BY
                              NIPX.d_date_begin DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS NIP
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (
                          SELECT
                              NIPX.link,
                              NIPX.f_parent
                          FROM dbo.ed_network_struct NIPX
                          WHERE NIPX.f_child = NP.f_network_pts
                            AND NIPX.b_pod = TRUE
                            AND NIPX.b_ismain = TRUE
                            AND NIPX.d_date_begin <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                          ORDER BY
                              NIPX.d_date_begin DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS NIP_P
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      ( 
                         SELECT
                             NRi.id,
                             NRi.c_network_path,
                             NRi.c_network_path_short
                         FROM dbo.ed_network_routes NRi
                         WHERE NRi.n_level = 0
                           AND NRi.link = COALESCE(NIP_P.f_parent, NIP.f_parent)
                           AND NOW() >= NRi.d_date0
                           AND NOW() < NRi.d_date1
                         ORDER BY
                             NRi.n_rate,
                             NRi.d_date1,
                             NRi.b_main DESC
                         LIMIT 1
                      ) AS NR
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_network_pts NI
                                ON NI.link = NIP.f_parent
                               AND NI.b_pod = FALSE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_network_pts NI_P
                                ON NI_P.link = NIP_P.f_parent
                               AND NI_P.b_pod = FALSE

                     /* Объект и адрес */
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.sd_conn_points CP
                                ON CP.link = NP.f_conn_points
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.sd_conn_points_sub CPS
                                ON CPS.link = NP.f_conn_points_sub
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.cs_conn_types CT
                                ON CT.link = CPS.f_conn_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_building_corp_type sbct
                                ON sbct.link = CP.f_building_corp_type
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_locations AS Provinces
                                ON Provinces.link = CP.f_provinces_fias
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_location_types AS LT_Provinces
                                ON LT_Provinces.link = Provinces.f_location_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_locations AS Towns
                                ON Towns.link = CP.f_towns_fias
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_location_types AS LT_Towns
                                ON LT_Towns.link = Towns.f_location_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_locations AS Municipalities
                                ON Municipalities.link = CP.f_municipalities_fias
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_location_types AS LT_Municipalities
                                ON LT_Municipalities.link = Municipalities.f_location_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_locations AS Streets
                                ON Streets.link = CP.f_streets_fias
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ss_location_types AS LT_Streets
                                ON LT_Streets.link = Streets.f_location_types /* Параметры ТУ */
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_areas AS erpa
                                ON erpa.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND erpa.d_date <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                               AND erpa.d_date_end > COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.sd_areas AS SDA
                                ON SDA.link = erpa.f_areas

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_loss AS RPL_Line 
                                ON RPL_Line.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND RPL_Line.f_loss_types = 1
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RPL_Line.d_date_begin AND RPL_Line.d_date_end
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_loss AS RPL_Transf 
                                ON RPL_Transf.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND RPL_Transf.f_loss_types = 2
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RPL_Transf.d_date_begin AND RPL_Transf.d_date_end
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_loss AS RPL_Non_Heat 
                                ON RPL_Non_Heat.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND RPL_Non_Heat.f_loss_types = 3
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RPL_Non_Heat.d_date_begin AND RPL_Non_Heat.d_date_end

                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (
                          SELECT
                              RPA1.n_rate,
                              RPA1.d_date,
                              RPA1.f_registr_pts
                          FROM dbo.ed_registr_pts_activity AS RPA1
                          WHERE RPA1.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                            AND RPA1.d_date <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                          ORDER BY
                              d_date DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS RPA
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_tariff AS RPT
                                ON RPT.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RPT.d_date AND RPT.d_date_end
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.fs_tariff AS FT
                                ON FT.link = RPT.f_tariff
                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (
                          SELECT
                              FTH.n_tariff,
                              FTH.n_tariff_2
                          FROM dbo.fs_tariff_history FTH
                          WHERE FTH.f_tariff = FT.link
                            AND FTH.b_default = TRUE
                            AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN FTH.d_date_begin AND FTH.d_date_end
                          ORDER BY
                              FTH.link
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS FTH
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_cap AS RCap
                                ON RCap.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND RCap.b_contract = FALSE
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RCap.d_date AND RCap.d_date_end

                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (
                          SELECT
                              RCon_.n_cons,
                              RCon_.n_cons2,
                              RCon_.d_date
                          FROM dbo.ed_registr_pts_cons AS RCon_
                          WHERE RP.link = RCon_.f_registr_pts
                            AND RCon_.b_contract = FALSE
                            AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RCon_.d_date AND RCon_.d_date_end
                          ORDER BY
                              RCon_.d_date
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS RCon
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_registr_pts_calc_methods AS RCM
                                ON RCM.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                               AND COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW()) BETWEEN RCM.d_date AND RCM.d_date_end
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_calc_methods AS ECM
                                ON ECM.link = RCM.f_calc_methods
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_calc_methods AS ECM2
                                ON ECM2.link = RCM.f_calc_methods_default

                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL
                      (
                          SELECT
                              EDP1.link,
                              EDP1.f_devices,
                              EDP1.f_energy_types,
                              EDP1.n_percent,
                              EDP1.n_percent2,
                              EDP1.b_main,
                              EDP1.f_division
                          FROM dbo.ed_devices_pts EDP1
                               INNER JOIN dbo.ed_devices D1
                                          ON D1.link = EDP1.f_devices
                                         AND D1.d_setup_date <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                          WHERE EDP1.f_registr_pts = RP.link
                          ORDER BY
                              D1.d_setup_date DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                      ) AS EDP
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.ed_devices D
                                ON D.link = EDP.f_devices
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_device_types EDT
                                ON EDT.link = D.f_device_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_device_categories EDC
                                ON EDC.link = EDT.f_device_categories
                      LEFT JOIN LATERAL dbo.ef_device_digits_list(D.link) AS Dig
                      ON TRUE

                      LEFT JOIN dbo.fs_sale_items AS FSI
                                ON FSI.link = RP.f_sale_items
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.fs_sale_categories AS FSC
                                ON FSC.link = RP.f_sale_category
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_energy_levels AS EEL
                                ON EEL.link = RP.f_energy_levels
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_balance_types AS EBT
                                ON EBT.link = RP.f_balance_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_loss_algorithms AS ELA
                                ON ELA.link = RP.f_transf_algorithms
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_loss_algorithms AS ELA2
                                ON ELA2.link = RP.f_line_algorithms
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_loss_algorithms AS ELA3
                                ON ELA3.link = RP.f_non_heat_algorithms


                      LEFT JOIN dbo.fs_norms FN
                                ON FN.link = RPT.f_norms
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_transf_types AS ETT
                                ON ETT.link = RP.f_transf_types
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_work_modes AS ESWM
                                ON ESWM.link = RCap.f_work_modes
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.es_energy_types AS EET
                                ON EET.link = EDP.f_energy_types

                 WHERE RP.d_date_begin <= COALESCE(_D_Date, NOW())
                   AND RP.f_division = COALESCE(_F_Division, RP.f_division)
                   AND (
                        _F_Areas = -1
                        OR _F_Areas = erpa.f_areas
                        OR (
                            _F_Areas IS NULL
                            AND erpa.f_areas IS NULL
                           )
                        OR (
                            _F_Areas IS NULL
                            AND erpa.f_areas = 0
                           )
                       );
END;
$$;
```

Initially, I thought the problem was in the tables used, because the structure has changed, but I checked the function with the replacement with the necessary ones, nothing has changed. So I think the problem is not in the tables.

Comment: I attach a link to the file with the MS SQL procedure, because I can't insert the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Vc7y-DFZfu1ypq6lnN_zEErC7inuNMj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is possible that indexes on your tables in SQL Server do not exist on the PostgreSQL side, or perhaps you have not created them. However, to know more precisely why the query is running so late, it is recommended that using `explain analyze` and see plan.